# ASP.Net - Change XML files values

Tags: asp.net

We receive dynamic type of XML from various system. We want to change values of some parameters in XML files.

Can somebody please advise, how can we in .NET - modify values in XML files

Regards
Palak

Comment: ..You read the file, change the data, and write it to the same file. Are you having any issues with your existing code?

Comment: Dod you at least google '.NET - modify values in XML files'?

Comment: as I'm new to .net, i have not written any code yet. so any directions would help.

Comment: @user3657339: You could start by searching for "c# xml" in your favorite search engine. Look into the XmlSerializer and XDocument classes, pick the tool you need and create something and see what happens. If you are experiencing any issues, come back with a specific question and we'd be happy to guide you then.